# Pushing object into mongoDB, ["object Object"] is saved

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object

Sorry if this is a repetitive one, I really couldn't solve it with any of the information provided here.

Basically I have this in my User.js mongoDB schema:

```
notifications: [{
        type: String,
        story: String,
        seen: Boolean,
        createdTime: Date,
        from: {
            name: String,
            username: String,
            id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId
        }
    }]
```

After I query the user, this is what I do to push this object:

```
var notifObj = {

    type: notification.type,
    story: notification.story || ' ',
    seen: false,
    createdTime: new Date(),
    from: {
        name: notification.from.firstName + " " + notification.from.lastName,
        username: notification.from.username,
        id: notification.from._id
    }
};
```

into the mongoDB database:

```
user.notifications.push(notifObj);

User.update({
    _id: notification.to
}, user, function(err, data) {

    if (err) {

        deferred.reject({
            err: err
        });
    }

    //Tell sender everything went alrgiht
    deferred.resolve(data);
});
```

P.S.: I have `deferred.resolve` instead of res.end(), because I push notifications on some of the requests in a different controller, I don't have a separate route only for notifications. (e.g.: User has a new message, I send the message and push a notification too)

Comment: Are you sure it's saving as [object object], or is that just how it displays when you try to console.log the object? Try logging a property on the object that is a simple type, like `notifObj.seen`

Comment: Check the answer, you will not be sure whether to laugh or to facepalm... :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out why mongoDB was always converting my Object to `String` and giving me an ["object Object"] and the reason is very simple - NEVER use reserved/common words for object keys. MongoDB was interpreting my `notification: {type: String, ...}` as a field, which holds a String as value and not as a notification, which has type, seen and other properties. A quick fix to my User.js Schema is:

```
notifications: [{
        notifType: String,
        story: String,
        seen: Boolean,
        createdTime: Date,
        from: {
            name: String,
            username: String,
            id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId
    }]
```